# Referring to a cell address/reference inside a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to refer to the last cell that contains a text by its address (ex, C800) inside the MIN function. Can you help please?

```
Sub Set_Formula()
' -----------------------------

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Lastcell As Range
Dim LC As String

Set Lastcell = Range("C:C").Find("*", Range("C1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Set LC = Lastcell.Address()

'find last cell in the row
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim r As Long
For r = 2 To lastRow
    If (Cells(r, 3).Value <> "") Then 
        Range("E8") _
        = "=MIN(C2:LC)" 'The MIN function 
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not how I would do this, but :

```
Range("E8") _
    = "=MIN(C2:" & LC & ")" 'The MIN function
End If
```

and, in your code, since LC is a string and not an object, be sure to remove the `Set` word.

That, of course, puts a static formula into `E8`.

So, if column `C` changes (more data added below LC, for example), you'll need to rewrite the formula to the worksheet.

If you prefer a formula that automagically adjusts to changing numbers of rows in column C, you can use:

```
=MIN(INDEX($C$2:INDEX($C:$C,LOOKUP(9.9E+307,$C:$C,ROW($C:$C))),0,1))
```

**Edit**: *(Explanation of the formula)*

The formula uses a feature of the `LOOKUP` function to find the last row. When `lookup_value` is greater than any value in `lookup_array`, `LOOKUP` will match the last value in `lookup_array`.  Since we are using the optional `result_vector` argument, `LOOKUP` returns the value in the matching position which is that row number.

By using a very large number as lookup_value, one that is close to the maximum number allowed in Excel, we assure that there will not be a larger number in `lookup_array`

We then use the `INDEX` function to create an array that begins with `C2` (or whatever you put in for a starting cell) and ends and `Cn` where `n` is the row number returned by the `LOOKUP` function.

Comment: your suggested formula refers to the whole column C right ? because in my file, I will have to refer it from C33 to last cell that contains a text. However, Thank you for your clarification on my code, It worked as you said.

Comment: @RayanBared. No, it does not.  It refers to `C2:last_cell_containing_number` For the suggested formula, merely change the `$C$2` to whatever cell you want for the start of the range.  I used `C2` only because that's what you used in your code.

Comment: @RayanBared Also, in your question and comment, you write `contains a text`, but your VBA code is looking for `*`, which would match anything (text or number).  My recommended formula looks for last row containing a `number`, which should be functionally equivalent since `MIN` ignores text.

Comment: Can you explain what does 9.9+307 refer to exactly please if you don't mind. Thank you

Comment: @RayanBared See the Edit in my answer for an explanation of the formula.

Comment: @RayanBared Oh, also there was a typo which I have corrected.  That should have been **`9.9E+307`**

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the value for lastRow: `Range("E8") = "=MIN(C2:C" & lastRow & ")"`